# if string begins with "xx" (PHP)

Tags: php, session

```
if ($_POST['id'] beginsWith "gm") {
$_SESSION['game']=="gmod"
}
if ($_POST['id'] beginsWith "tf2") {
$_SESSION['game']=="tf2"
}
```

How to do this so it will work?

Comment: you have to write a patch in C code that adds this keyword/syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (strpos($_POST['id'], "gm") === 0) {
  $_SESSION['game'] ="gmod"
}
if (strpos($_POST['id'],"tf2") === 0) {
  $_SESSION['game'] ="tf2"
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. If strpos returns false, both of those if statements will evaluate to true.

Comment: @andrewtweber: There.  Replaced the `==` with `===` :-P

Answer (score 35):

You could use [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
if(substr($POST['id'],0,3) == 'tf2')
 {
  //Do something
 }
```

Edit: fixed incorrect function name (`substring()` used, should be `substr()`)

Comment: +1. this should be (marginally) faster than strpos since it won't traverse the entire string on failure.

Comment: @EmilVikström I **seriously** doubt your statement about `substr()` being faster than `strpos()`. In fact I believe it will be *slower*!

Answer (score 23):

You can write a `begins_with` using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
function begins_with($haystack, $needle) {
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}


if (begins_with($_POST['id'], "gm")) {
    $_SESSION['game']=="gmod"
}

// etc
```

Answer (score 3):

NOT the fastest way to do it but you can use regex

```
if (preg_match("/^gm/", $_POST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['game']=="gmod"
}
if (preg_match("/^tf2/, $_POST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['game']=="tf2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function startswith($haystack, $needle){ 
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}

if (startswith($_POST['id'], 'gm')) {
    $_SESSION['game'] = 'gmod';
}
if (startswith($_POST['id'], 'tf2')) {
    $_SESSION['game'] = 'tf2';
}
```

Note that when assigning values to variable use a single =